# Use namespace to distinguish between two IUnitOfWork implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api, with C#, .NET Framework 4.0, Entity Framework Code First 6.0 and Ninject.

I will need two different `DbContext` custom implementations because I need to connect with two different databases.

This is one of my custom `DbContext` class implementation.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public EFDbContext()
        : base("name=EFDbContext")
    {
        // If database doesn't exit, don't create it.
        Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CONFIGURATIONSConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CODESConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AGGREGATIONSConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Both `DbContext` custom classes will inherit from `IUnitOfWork` and my problem if that I don't know how to distinguish between them on `NinjectConfigurator` class:

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
{
    ConfigureLog4net(container);

    container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EFDbContext>().InRequestScope();

    // Hidden implementation...
}
```

If I have two different `EFDbContext` classes, how can I distinguish them on `NinjectConfigurator`?

Maybe I can use the same `IUnitOfWork` interface with two different name space and use the name space to distinguish between them. The problem here is that I will have the same interface repeated in two different name spaces.

Comment: They should be distinguished by class name really. Rename the context to refer to the database you are connecting to and it may sound more logical. So now you have context called something like `OrdersDatabaseContext` and another one called `CustomersContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name them.

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EFDbContext>().Named("EF");
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<OtherDbContext>().Named("Other");
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
class MyRepository {
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public([Named("EF")] IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954374/ninject-named-binding-with-igenericrepository, related to this one. I use a Generic repository and I don't know how to use your answer with it.

Comment: Took the liberty of answering it aswell ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create interfaces for both contexts.
For example `IEFDbContext1` and `IEFDbContext2`. Then your code can be:

```
Bind<IEFDbContext1>().To<EFDbContext1>().InRequestScope();
Bind<IEFDbContext2>().To<EFDbContext2>().InRequestScope();
```

And it's also a good idea to give more meaningful names, because currently EFDbContext doesn't tell much of his responsibilities.

I think that using separate interfaces can also help you in unit testing, if you need to mock contexts.