# Ninject Named binding with IGenericRepository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api, with C#, .NET Framework 4.0, Entity Framework Code First 6.0 and Ninject.

I have two different `DbContext` custom implementations to connect with two different databases.

This is my `NinjectConfigurator` class (partial):

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
{
    container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().
       To<TRZICDbContext>().InRequestScope().Named("TRZIC");
    container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().
       To<INICDbContext>().InRequestScope().Named("INIC");

    container.Bind<IGenericRepository<CONFIGURATIONS>>().
       To<GenericRepository<CONFIGURATIONS>>();
    container.Bind<IGenericRepository<INCREMENTAL_TABLE>>().
    To<GenericRepository<INCREMENTAL_TABLE>>();

    // More implementation...
}
```

`CONFIGURATIONS` is a `TRZIC` table and `INCREMENTAL_TABLE` is an `INIC` table.

I'm using a `IGenericRepository` and here it's where I have the problems:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        dbContext = (DbContext)unitOfWork;
        DbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // Hidden implementation..
}
```

I don't know how to use the `[Named("TRZIC")]` here `public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)` or maybe I need to use it elsewhere.

Here the `IUnitOfWork` implementation depends on TEntity.

Any advice?

Comment: Consider using interfaces as I suggested in your previous question.

Comment: @Alex I can't use your interfaces here because I'm using the same `IGenericRepository` for both databases. Here, the IUnitOfWork implementation depends on TEntity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
{
    container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<TRZICDbContext>().InRequestScope();

    container.Bind<IGenericRepository<CONFIGURATIONS>>().
        To<GenericRepository<CONFIGURATIONS>>();
    container.Bind<IGenericRepository<INCREMENTAL_TABLE>>().
        To<GenericRepository<INCREMENTAL_TABLE>>().WithConstructorArgument("unitOfWork", new INICDbContext());

    // More code..
}
```

I have used `WithConstructorArgument` to indicate that I want to use `INICDbContext`.

I don't know if this is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the basics.

As far as i know named bindings work only with constant values attributed in code, like the `[Named("foo")]` attribute, or otherwise by using "service location" like `IResolutionRoot.Get<T>(string name)`. Either does not work for your scenario, so a named binding is out of the question.
That leaves you with conditional bindings (`.When(...)` methods).

---

You've got 2 database with n entities each.
2 Database means two configurations means 2 different `IUnitOfWork` configuration.
However, the "user" is not requesting a specific database, but a specific entity.
Thus you'll need a map `entity-->database` (a dictionary). I don't think there's a way to get around that, but you may devise some kind of convention & implement it by convention, so you don't have to type and maintain a lot of code.

**Solution 1: `.WhenInjectedInto<>`**

with out of the box ninject features, and lots of manual labor:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkOfDatabaseA>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IRepository<SomeEntityOfDatabaseA>>();

Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkOfDatabaseA>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IRepository<SomeOtherEntityOfDatabaseA>>();

Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkOfDatabaseB>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IRepository<SomeEntityOfDatabaseB>>();
```

you get the drift,.. right?

---

**Solution 2.1: Custom `When(..)` implementation**

Not so much manual labor and maintenance anymore.
Let me just dump the code on you, see below:

public interface IRepository
    {
        IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
    }

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork { }
class UnitOfWorkA : IUnitOfWork { }
class UnitOfWorkB : IUnitOfWork { }

public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void asdf()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(typeof (IRepository<>)).To(typeof (Repository<>));

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkA>()
            .When(request => IsRepositoryFor(request, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(bool) })); // these are strange entity types, i know ;-)

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkB>()
            .When(request => IsRepositoryFor(request, new[] { typeof(int), typeof(double) }));


        // assert
        kernel.Get<IRepository<string>>()
            .UnitOfWork.Should().BeOfType<UnitOfWorkA>();

        kernel.Get<IRepository<double>>()
            .UnitOfWork.Should().BeOfType<UnitOfWorkB>();

    }

    private bool IsRepositoryFor(IRequest request, IEnumerable<Type> entities)
    {
        if (request.ParentRequest != null)
        {
            Type injectInto = request.ParentRequest.Service;
            if (injectInto.IsGenericType && injectInto.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IRepository<>))
            {
                Type entityType = injectInto.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                return entities.Contains(entityType);
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2.2 Custom convention based `When(...)`**

Let's introduce a small convention. Entity names of database TRZIC start with `TRZIC`, for example `TRZIC_Foo`. Entity names of database INIC start with `INIC`, like `INIC_Bar`. We can now adapt the previous solution to:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void asdf()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(typeof (IRepository<>)).To(typeof (Repository<>));

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkA>()
            .When(request => IsRepositoryFor(request, "TRZIC")); // these are strange entity types, i know ;-)

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWorkB>()
            .When(request => IsRepositoryFor(request, "INIC"));


        // assert
        kernel.Get<IRepository<TRZIC_Foo>>()
            .UnitOfWork.Should().BeOfType<UnitOfWorkA>();

        kernel.Get<IRepository<INIC_Bar>>()
            .UnitOfWork.Should().BeOfType<UnitOfWorkB>();
    }

    private bool IsRepositoryFor(IRequest request, string entityNameStartsWith)
    {
        if (request.ParentRequest != null)
        {
            Type injectInto = request.ParentRequest.Service;
            if (injectInto.IsGenericType && injectInto.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IRepository<>))
            {
                Type entityType = injectInto.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                return entityType.Name.StartsWith(entityNameStartsWith, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This way we don't need explicit mapping `(EntityA, EntityB, EntityC) => DatabaseA`, `(EntityD, EntityE, EntityF) => DatabaseB)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that `IUnitOfWork` depends on `TEntity` why not make `IUnitOfWork` generic too?

```
public class TRZIC {}

public class INIC {}

public interface IUnitOfWork<TEntity> {}

public class TRZICDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork<TRZIC> {}

public class INICDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork<INIC> {}

public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> {}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork<TEntity> unitOfWork)
    {
        var dbContext = (DbContext) unitOfWork;
    }
}

private static void AddBindings(IKernel container)
{
    container
        .Bind<IUnitOfWork<TRZIC>>()
        .To<TRZICDbContext>();
    container
        .Bind<IUnitOfWork<INIC>>()
        .To<INICDbContext>();

    container
        .Bind<IGenericRepository<TRZIC>>()
        .To<GenericRepository<TRZIC>>();
    container
        .Bind<IGenericRepository<INIC>>()
        .To<GenericRepository<INIC>>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that also leverages code readability:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork {}

// both named A and B
public class UnitOfWorkA : IUnitOfWork {}

public class UnitOfWorkB : IUnitOfWork {}

public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        dbContext = (DbContext)unitOfWork;
        DbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

     // other IGenericRepository methods

}

public class GenericRepositoryForA<TEntity> : GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    public GenericRepositoryForA([Named("A")]IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}

public class GenericRepositoryForB<TEntity> : GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    public GenericRepositoryForB([Named("B")]IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

This allows you to ask for a specific database context as a dependency, or get both of them if required. And you only need to implement `GenericRepository` once.

It greatly improvises code visiblity because you actually know which database context you are using by looking at the variable type/name, instead of getting a `IUnitOfWork` injected without any visual detail on its actual type.

I'd suggest adding some extra interfaces if you want to unittest it (you should!).

Simply adding

```
public interface IGenericRepositoryForA<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
```

and just let `GenericRepositoryForA<TEntity>` implement it aswell.